# How to install a mmc certificate on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I am not familiar with Windows very much, and I have trouble installing a MMC certificate. I am following [this description](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019527) to use MMC to create a certificate, but I cannot complete the step labeled ' Install or view the certificates under:'. There is nothing unter 'ConsoleRoot' -> 'Certificates (Local Computer)' -> 'Personal', and when I try to find the certificate I cannot find it.

There is [another page](http://www.databasemart.com/howto/SQLoverssl/How_To_Import_Personal_Certificate_With_MMC.aspx) with nice screenshots, which works until step 9 when I am about to choose the certificate file. I do not know where this file is been created, if at all.

How can I create/install/import this certificate? I require this in order to use the powershell `Enter-PSSession` from a remote machine...

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you do not create certificates with MMC. You have to have a certificate file, know where it is in the filesystem, and then you have to [add the console snap-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754431(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) if you want to handle certificates graphically

When you've added the MMC snap-in you then install/import the certificate